# Converting color Video to black and white using MPMovie Player in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, ios4, mpmovieplayer

I am implementing a video based application. In that I need to support the conversion of a color video to black and white. I am using MPMoviePlayer to play the video. Is this feature supported using MPMovieplayer? Pleases suggest.

Thanks in advance,
Chandra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no API provided with MPMOviePlayer to achieve this functionality.

Comment: @ Krishnan, Thanks for the responce, Is there any other way to implement this. Please suggest.

Comment: Chandrasekar, I am not aware if there is any way to do it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Krishnan, I will research on this and update you if I got any solution.